# php not passing data to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php page that connects to a mysql database.  I know that the connection to the database is good because I have a php code that displays info from the database onto the webpage. When I try to insert new data into the databse, the page refreshes and the data is not inserted.  I have checked to insure that the insert into command has the correct values.

```
      <?php 

    if (isset($_POST['User_Name'])) 
        {

            include "connect_to_mysql.php";

            $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Name"]);

            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT TestID FROM test WHERE Name='$name' LIMIT 1")or die (mysql_error());
            $productMatch = mysql_num_rows($sql); 

            if ($productMatch > 0) 
                {
                    echo 'Sorry you tried to place a duplicate "User Account" into the system, <a href="index.php">click here</a>';
                    exit();
                }
                else
                {

                    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (TestID,Name) 
                        VALUES('', '$name')") or die (mysql_error());
                     $uid = mysql_insert_id();

                    header("location: index.php"); 
                    exit();
                }
        }
?>
<?php 

    include "connect_to_mysql.php";
    $User_list = "";
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test");
    $UserCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); 
    if ($UserCount > 0) 
        {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
                { 
                         $id = $row["TestID"];
                         $name = $row["Name"];

                         $User_list .= "Users ID: $id - <strong>$name</strong>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<br />";
                }
        } 
        else 
        {
            $User_list = "You have no users listed in the database.";
        }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div align="center" id="mainWrapper">
  <div id="pageContent"><br />
    <div align="right" style="margin-right:32px;"><a href="index.php#UserForm">+ Add New User</a></div>
<div align="left" style="margin-left:24px;">
      <h2>User list</h2>
      <?php echo $User_list; ?>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <a name="UserForm" id="UserForm"></a>
    <h3>
    &darr; Add New User Form &darr;
    </h3>
    <form action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm" id="myform" method="post">
    <table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
      <tr>
        <td width="20%" align="right">Name</td>
        <td width="80%"><label>
          <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="50" />
        </label></td>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><label>
          <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add This Name Now" />
        </label></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    <br />
  <br />
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you could try opening an instance of MySQL, and try inserting the data straight from there? Since when you try to insert stuff into a DB with PHP, it doesn't really tell you what went wrong, but if you use MySQL directly, it'll tell you what's wrong (probably something like an un-escaped quote or something minor but hard to catch).

Comment: It is not recommended to use the old `mysql_*()` functions anymore. They are planned for deprecation. Instead consider using a modern API supporting prepared statements, such as PDO or MySQLi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems right away (there may be more). First, PHP array keys are case sensitive. You are accessing `$_POST['Name']` but your form input is `name`. Second, you are testing for `$_POST['User_Name']` which doesn't appear to exist anywhere:

```
// Look for name in the $_POST
if (isset($_POST['name'])) 
{
    include "connect_to_mysql.php";
    // name is case-sensitive
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["name"]);
```

Later, if your table has an AUTO_INCREMENT id on `TestID`, you should either omit it or insert NULL in the insert statment:

```
// Don't include TestID if it is AUTO_INCREMENT. That will happen automatically
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (Name) 
                    VALUES('$name')") or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thnx for the help guys, that fixed it.  Can't beleive I missed something simple like that.  Guess spending all day coding with out breaks is not a good ideal....lol.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work if you change

```
 if (isset($_POST['User_Name']))
```

to

```
if (isset($_POST['Name']))
```

You check the existence of something which doesn't exists in your form.

Answer (score 0):

***Addition:***

If `TestID` is autoincrement, change the below

```
"INSERT INTO test (TestID,Name) VALUES('', '$name')"
```

to

```
"INSERT INTO test (Name) VALUES('$name')"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not get any errors that means you have an error in your MySQL syntax two ways to test it would be to copy the syntax into PHPMyAdmin or whatever your native MySQL command line is and see if you get an output error. Or another thing you can do is to modify all your `mysql_query()`; functions by adding `mysql_query()or die(mysql_error());`